# Use Doctrine to search into a json database column

Tags: json, doctrine

I have a Symfony 3.2 project, and I need to **filter data from a json column**.
Given that we have an entity named *"pack"* with a json column named *"settings"* containing this kind of data:

```
{
  "name": "My pack",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "name": "Block 1",
      "fields": [
        {"label": "A", "value": "57"},
        {"label": "B", "value": "100"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Bock 2",
      "fields": [
        {"label": "C", "value": "80"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to search *packs* with a field which has the *label* "B" and its *value* at "100", but each *pack* doesn't have same blocks and fields order.
So in my repository, using **Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository** and **[opsway/doctrine-dbal-postgresql](https://github.com/opsway/doctrine-dbal-postgresql)** *(for GET_JSON_FIELD and GET_JSON_OBJECT functions)*, this kind of condition works:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class Packs extends EntityRepository
{
  public function findFiltered(...)
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('pack')
      ->andWhere("GET_JSON_FIELD(GET_JSON_OBJECT(pack.settings, '{blocks,0,fields,1}'), 'label') = :label")
      ->andWhere("GET_JSON_FIELD(GET_JSON_OBJECT(pack.settings, '{blocks,0,fields,1}'), 'value') = :value")
      ->setParameter('label', 'B')
      ->setParameter('value', '100')
    ;
  }
}
```

But the problem is that I have to specify the precise block *(the first block object)*, and the precise field *(the second field object of the first block object)*. And my two condition aren't connected, it search if there is a label "B", then it search if there is a value "100". **When I would like to have a research in all blocks and fields to find the good label for the good value.** Any idea?

---

I found the good SQL request for my problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM pack p, json_array_elements(p.settings#>'{blocks}') blocks, json_array_elements(blocks#>'{fields}') fields
WHERE  fields->>'label' = 'B' and fields->>'value' = '100';
```

But how I do that **with doctrine**?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [link](https://gist.github.com/thomas-seres/301c43649d40ebd947a9ac1f6aee681d) can help you, it is a custom filter for a JSON type field, maybe it will serve as an example, but [these](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) functions with [this](https://github.com/ScientaNL/DoctrineJsonFunctions) bundle solved the problem for me. I hope this helps someone else too. Cheers!